# How to use "street view" in Google maps on Xperia Mini ST15i?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-maps

I'm unable to switch to the street view when using the Google maps on my android phone. I updated the Google maps to the latest version and also the street view but unable still though. I turned off the `satellite view` and tried but the street view was still disable. I tried to finding informative videos regarding this and some forums but they didn't helped me. I would really appreciated if any one help me about this.

[image]

Comment: To make absolutely sure that street view is disabled because of your hardware, try to access street view on a street in a major city.  There are some streets where street view hasn't been captured.  These are usually back streets in small towns.

Comment: @ctt it is not supporting anywhere for me.

Comment: Working ok for me on same handset, might be down to the fact I have ICS on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, Street View imagery is not available for your location (yet).

- Cross check the web version with any PC for the same location that doesn't work on your phone
- Check a well-supported Street View location such as [Google HQ](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Google,+Inc,+Plymouth+Street,+Mountain+View,+CA,+United+States&hl=de&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=62.226996,135.263672&oq=google+inc&t=h&hq=Google,+Inc,+Plymouth+Street,+Mountain+View,+CA,+United+States&z=15) on your phone

Answer (score 0):

It may take a couple of second for the Street View button to become enabled. Just leave the button for up to half a minute?

Comment: I leaved it at least for 1 minute but the button still disabled. :(

Answer (score -2):

Check [the tables of supported countries on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Street_View#Table). Most likely, Street View is not yet available where you live.

Comment: That is **not** an answer by referring to a linky to wikipedia - suggest you re-edit your answer!